# Does Confluent schema registry only support AVRO?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

Can we use schema registry for json messages and json schemas? Or is it like we have to use avro serialization for value serialization of messages.

Comment: SO is really a forum for code help, not product support. There are a number of Apache user forums that would be a better place for your question.

Comment: What research did you do for this question?

Answer (score 1):

Confluent schema registry also support JSON schema and Protobuf with the release of Confluent Platform 5.5. It has been announced in this [blog](https://www.confluent.io/blog/confluent-platform-now-supports-protobuf-json-schema-custom-formats/).

Comment: It supports *JSON Schema* -- not JSON on its own.